# How to retrieve a value from the database function in joomla module?

Tags: php, database, function, joomla

How do I retrieve a value from the `database` function in `joomla` `module`?

Here is my code:

```
$indirect = "select GetAncestry('".$userID."');";
$db->setQuery($indirect);

$getVal  = $db->query();
echo "getVal" . $getVal ."<br>";//process breaks here
```

Comment: what the error you got?

Comment: Just realize - Answered too quickly - Can u explain with your words what the query should return ? Or show us the table.

Comment: @Siva.G It doesn't error out. It breaks out of the for loop.I have a for loop outside this function call to get parents(recursive) for every child(user_id).

Comment: @Falt4rmI am expecting the return value from the function which is the parent of the child.

Comment: what joomla version you have used?

Comment: @Siva.G Joomla 3.3.6

Comment: What is the query that you want to generate? If nothing else you will want `$somevar = $db->loadResult();` to actually execute the query (assuming you want just one result).  I'd recommend reading the documentation at docs.joomla.org.

Comment: Please show your full code cause from what I'm seeing, you're not even initiating a database connection using `JFactory::getDbo();`

Comment: @Lodder I am initializing the database conenction.

Comment: @Elin Am I not supposed to receive the return value from the function in $getVal?

Comment: No that's the query. You need to execute the query. Look at any example in core or go read the documentation about how to use JDatabaseQuery.